# Can I use electrical tape instead of the plastic tab when replacing my hard-drive?

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, hardware, ssd

I'm replacing the hard-drive on my 2010 Macbook Pro, (This machine just keeps going, and I'm finally upgrading it to a SSD!) and I'm almost done (it's simple enough) but the plastic tab from the original hard drive just won't stick to the new SSD. I was wondering if I can use some electrical tape instead? I know that short-term it shouldn't be an issue, but these machines can get really hot and I'm afraid that the tape might turn into a gummy mess inside my computer over time. Has anyone tried this? Did it last?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I definitely would not use electrical tape. Honestly, if for some reason you do not have the plastic tab that came on the HDD, then you can go without it when you replace it with the SSD. The opening is large enough you can get a finger between the SSD and the side rails, should you ever need to replace it. You can see [this article](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4727835?tstart=0) for another opinion on the matter.

Answer (score 2):

I have had luck using double sided tape when working my Macs. You need to buy a good brand such as Scotch. Price should be < $4 US. Although, I have never tried using this tape to hold the plastic tab on a drive.

[image]

Comment: I'd go with this. Electrical tape will leave a gooey residue, but double-sided Scotch tape should work well short and long term.